# Set root object for angular binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to bind a root object into an html tag and have the children of that tag bind to the properties of that object? In the same way that ng-repeat works but the object in question here is not a collection. Say I have an object with the following properties

```
$scope.obj = {
   a : 1,
   b : 2
};
```

and within my markup I have a div with two input elements inside

```
<div>
 <input type="text"></input>
 <input type="text"></input>
</div>
```

Is there a way to specify the root object and bind its properties in a similar manner

```
<div rootObject="object">
 <input type="text" ng-model="a"></input>
 <input type="text" ng-model="b"></input>
</div>
```

now both of the input elements are bound to `obj.a` and `obj.b` respectively.

I have a complex object with different objects nested inside, and objects of different types. Therefore the `ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj"` syntax does not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can still use ng-repeat:

```
<div rootObject="object">
    <input ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj" type="text" ng-model="object[key]" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is an application I was unaware of, but this only works when the child elements are all the same, and all the properties of the object are of the same type. I have a complex object with other objects nested inside and such, therefore I need something a bit more flexible.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific on what your data looks like then. Can you update your example?

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax of `ng-repeat` to bind it to the key/value pairs in an object

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj"
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('myCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
      <span>{{key}}</span>
      <input type="text" value="{{value}}" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```